# How to convert a curl command to java apache HttpPost?

Tags: java, curl, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I can't figure out how to replicate certain elements of the curl command below(for example the -L or any boolean/switch variable) parameter to a java http post

The curl command:

```
curl -L -XPOST localhost:4001/db?pretty -d 'some data'
```

The httppost so far:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient=HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postURL);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(someData));
//  httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("L")); This doesn't work
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
message = handler.handleResponse(response);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you must understand what the parameter does in curl. After understanding the concept, you should seek for how to accomplish that functionality using the framework.

Comment: The -X on curl is referred to Stream, so you need to use `InputStreamEntity` instead of `StringEntity`